# Not sure I'm quite understanding jQuery delegate

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a link that loads dynamic content into a div... there need to be a ton of additional ajax actions within that newly loaded dynamic content. Do I have to create a new delegate function for each of those actions in my success handler? (Does the delegate function, ideally belong in the success handler?) How can I consolidate these functions?

For example, I click the "view posts" button on the main screen.  It loads in a bunch of posts into a modal window.  Within that window, for example, there may be a 'view comments' button for each post, which makes its own ajax call and loads the comments directly into the modal window.

The two things I would like clarification on are what is the best practice for organizing these delegate functions.  Secondly, when is delegate required/when is it not required?

Edit: Thanks guys. These were all great answers.  I'm going to choose Ohgodwhy's answer because he only has 245 rep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a great reference to the jQuery delegate function found in the jQuery documentation located at -> http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Delegate monitors a "parent" and applies a function that allows for a callback on all child elements, regardless if they're dynamic or not.

```
$("table").delegate("td", "click", function(){
  //All actions to be performed regardless if dynamic or not.
});
```

What's important to note is that the delegate feature has since been replaced by the .on function in jQuery 1.7. You can monitor all DOM changes with the .on feature, which is also a replacement of the .live function.

The proper syntax to monitor and ensure that functions are bound to all elements added on/after DOM load is ->

```
$("table").on("click", "td", function(){
  //perform actions here for the click functions 
});
```

**EDIT**

If you wanted to target all  tag s with a class of "george" and ensure that the functions are run on all that are currently and will be in the future loaded, then you would do

```
$(".modal_overlay").on("click", ".george", function(){
  alert('I have a class of George');
  //every item with a class of george when clicked will alert this.
});
```

This should make sense.

Comment: So would I put the on or delegate functions at the top of my script, and it will also effect newly loaded content to the page?  So in my case, I'm loading content into a '.modal_overlay' ... Would I create a bunch of $('.modal_overlay').delegate functions at the top of my script?

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to delegate always on a static parent. So regardless of how many nested dynamic elements you have, if your container is, let's say an `<article>`, you'd do something like:

```
$('article').on('click', '.view-comments', function(){
    // Something
});
```

All `.view-comments` buttons inside of `<article>` and future ones will have a `click()` event regardless of the depth.

Comment: Okay, but but you missed the second part of the question.

Comment: You mean _...when is delegate required/when is it not required_?

Comment: No, the part about how to organize the function/where they belong within the script.  Thanks for the answer though, gave it a vote up.

Answer (score 1):

It's all about event bubbling. Consider the following HTML structure:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <p>
            Here's a 
            <a>link</a>
            and
            <a>another</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

If you were to click on the 'another' link, you're actually clicking on the `<a>`, the `<p>`, the `<div>` and the `<body>` tags too, since they're nested inside each other. This is what `.delegate` leverages to make events on dynamically added content simple. Let's say you attach a delegate event to the `<div>` element:

```
$('div').delegate('a', 'click', doSomething);
```

This means that when a click event bubbles to the div, it will check whether that same click event 'bubbled through' an `<a>` element inside itself and if so, then run the handler. The benefit here obviously is that the content of this div can be dynamic and could be modified after the delegate is added, since the selector is only checked when the event is fired.

Comment: So let's say I'm loading my content dynamically into a '.modal_overlay' ... would I create a bunch of delegate functions at the top of my page?  Or within the ajax success handler?  For instance, would I do $('.modal_overlay).delegate('.view_comments', click', function() {}) ?

Comment: @ThinkingInBits yep, exactly right. In general, you should attach your delegate function to the element which won't be changing. That is, whatever is the container for your dynamic content.